# Text analysis problems with german grammar

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, coreml

How do solutions like DeepL deal with the german grammar, especially with partical verbs that are consisting of two parts. I want to use the Apple NLP for text analysis and it works great for detecting nouns, adjectives and verbs but if there is a partical verb with 2 parts in the beginning and the end of the sentence it will not detect them as one verb. But DeepL does that.

For example the word "Anfangen" (to  start) is a German particle verb. Consisting of two parts, a base verb (“fangen”) and particle (“an”). But "fangen" as a single word means to catch. So NLP need to check that there is a particle in the sentence that belongs to "fangen". It's hard to explain. Or is it all about machine learning?